# Структура паттерна MVC. Где хранить данные, общие для всех Views?

Tags: php, mvc, проектирование, шаблоны-проектирования

Пытаюсь разобраться с MVC и немного запутался. К примеру, у меня всё организовано следующим образом:

```
class Route {
    // разбирает REQUEST_URI на $controller_name / $action_name
    // загружает класс модели страницы, если существует
    // загружает класс контроллера страницы и вызывает стартовый метод
}

class Controller_page extends Controller {
    // создает объект модели страницы
    // создает объект представления
    // вызывает метод класса представления, который генерирует основной шаблон `template.php`
    // в основном шаблоне `include`-им представление для данного контроллера
}
```

Внимание, вопрос:

Основной шаблон `template.php` общий для всех, но так же содержит переменные. К примеру, `$site_title`, `$tite_logo`, ... имеет значение по-умолчанию, но может переопределяться в процессе выполнения скрипта. Например, если залогинился пользователь, или была загружена определённая страница. Вопрос: где правильно хранить и обновлять эти переменные основного шаблона? Было бы удобно в свойствах корневой модели, чтоб все модели страниц их наследовали, но, к примеру, у статических страниц модели нет. А хранить данные в представлении концепция не позволяет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Общие данные для всех видов передавайте из базового контроллера. Создайте класс например Controller_Application.

Пример наследования:

```
News extends Controller_Application

Controller_Application extends Controller
```

P.S
Каждый трактует по-своему взаимодействие слоев MVC, корректно будет из контроллера передавать данные в вид.

Comment: По своему опыту понял, что пока не поковыряешь какой-нибудь фреймворк - нихрена в этом деле не поймешь. Вот `Codeigniter` мне очень помог.